How does shooting into melee actually work?
Let's say a PC is engaged in a melee fight with a creature. (S)he draws a gun and shoots the creature point-blank. How this kind of situation is supposed to be resolved?
The rules say:

6.2.1 When someone shooting into melee scores a hit, assign a number to every potential target and roll a die. Whoever's number comes up receives the DAMAGE

This raises a lot of questions:

What is a potential target?
Can the shooter be such a target?
How do I assign numbers? Let's say there are two people. Should I assign 1, 2 and roll d6? Or should I assign 1-2-3 and 3-4-5? Something else?
Does the original target receive the damage regardless of the roll?


What shooting into melee is.
First, let's clarify what "shooting into melee" means: it means intending to harm a target who's engaged in hand-to-hand combat with one or several other people, some of whom you might wish to avoid hitting. This rule presents the chaotic and unpredictable nature of firing a projectile weapon into an ongoing physical fight. In such a circumstance, it's hard to sight and hit your quarry accurately. Rule 6.2.1. offers a way to represent this in the game. So, to your questions:

A potential target is someone engaged in melee combat who could reasonably be hit by the launched arrow, bolt, or stone.
Ranged attacks go away from the shooter into the melee, so the shooter is not a potential target.
Assign a number — "a" being a single number – to every potential target in the melee. In this case, assign 1 and 2 to the first and second combatant.
No. In the case above, you would assign damage to the first combatant if a 1 is rolled and to the second combatant if 2 is rolled, and no one would take damage if 3, 4, 5, or 6 were rolled.

…and what it isn't.
In the circumstance you describe, you don't need to use Rule 6.2.1. If it's just you with a crossbow [1] and someone else with a knife, you just use 6.2. In the general case, a shooter won't be in melee with their target; ranged weapons usually [2] require 2 hands to wield, so you don't have the means to fight hand-to-hand (in melee) while shooting. At best, you're shooting and someone else is hitting you. Moreover, the initiative system says you get one action on your turn, so you're either shooting or hitting, not both.

Modern handguns aren't on the gear list for TROIKA, so I used an example that is.
If you're using the one 1-handed ranged weapon, the sci-fi pistolet, and you're shooting at point-blank range while also engaged in a hand-to-hand fight (blaster and dagger, perhaps), I'd say that you're firing within melee, not into it, so shoot as normal.


So basically, point-blank shooting against one target is almost meaningless? Even on hit, you have just a 1/6 chance of dealing damage

@enkryptor This is only the case when you're firing on a target that's engaged in melee. If you're shooting at a single target, do it before your cohorts enter melee with them — that's one benefit of being at range.

Wait a second. So "someone shooting into melee" means the target is engaged melee, not the shooter?

@enkryptor Yes. These rules are for when you, the shooter, are aiming at a target that's engaged in hand-to-hand combat with one or several other people, some of whom you would like to avoid hitting.

What if the target is engaged in melee with the shooter? (a "knife vs gun" kind of situation)

@enkryptor This is outside the scope of the question, but I can try to address it. The initiative system says you get one action on your turn, so you're either shooting or hitting, not both. What's more, ranged weapons generally require 2 hands to wield, so you don't have the means to be fighting hand-to-hand (engaged in melee) while you're shooting. At best, you're shooting and someone else is hitting you. If you're using the one 1-handed ranged weapon, I'd say that you're firing within melee, not into it, so shoot as normal.

Does the game explain what it means to be "engaged in melee combat"? (I'm unfamiliar with this system, but my initial thought was that a person who shoots at a guy next to him with a knife would risk shooting himself. I'd kind of be okay with that. That's playable and darkly amusing.)

@HeyICanChan It does not. I'm relying on the common meanings of "melee" and "into" and my understanding of the game. ("Engaged" is my own language, because that's a useful way of conveying who's in melee and who's not.)

@Jadasc "This is outside the scope of the question" — it's quite the opposite, actually. The question was about this particular situation (shooting at point-blank range). It just was poorly worded.

@enkryptor This is so, which is why I changed my answer to address it once the scope of the question was clarified.
